# Server unable to parse a valid json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am making this ajax request to a url, but server is sending a response `Unrecognized token 'naejzraieale': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
 at [Source: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput@13367e3; line: 1, column: 25]`.

My Ajax request looks like this

```
$.ajax({url: "https://jsonparser.mydomain.com",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: "POST",
        data :{name : "juzer ali",
               email : "email@gmail.com",
               how : "Used jQuery.ajax from google chromes developer console",
               urls : ["https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/",                                  "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/", 
"https://github.com", "https://docs.google.com/document/d/edit?pli=1", "pro.appspot.com"]}
});
```

EDIT: Please notice `Unrecognized token 'naejzraieale':`. the `j` and `r` in this error string is from the name property of the object I am passing in data. When I capitalize the letters, I get `(Unrecognized token 'naeJZRAIeale': was expecting 'null', 'true',)`

Comment: Try encoding your data. If you see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263708/jquery-ajax-encoding-data, your contentType will require encoding

Comment: The server is expecting data in form of JSON, does it still require encoding? What is correct json MIME type anyway?

Comment: Try validating your JSON with http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

before sending data to server you need to encode it in JSON format
JSON.stringify and JSON.parse are provided by latest browsers but if any browser doesn't support that then you can use a jquery plugin to do the same http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/, if you use this plugin then the syntax would be different a little bit

```
$.ajax({
       url: "https://jsonparser.mydomain.com",
       type: 'POST',
       contentType:'application/json',
       data: JSON.stringify({name : "juzer ali",
               email : "email@gmail.com",
               how : "Used jQuery.ajax from google chromes developer console",
               urls : ["https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/",                                  "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/", 
"https://github.com/", "https://docs.google.com/document/d/edit?pli=1", "pro.appspot.com"]}),
       dataType:'json'
});
```

Comment: But why do I need to stringify it?? Doesn't jQuery do it on its own?

Comment: Although what you suggested has worked, I wonder why do I need to stringify my JSON, can't jQuery do it on its own?

Comment: nop jquery doesn't do it on its own, and the strange thing is that JQuery natively doesn't support converting data to JSON format, for that you have to use a plugin or native JSON object of browser

Comment: 3 years old but still as useful as today's. But its a shame that one has to do this manually after defining the content type