# Jacskon parser : Unrecognized token 'tieheT': was expecting 'null', 'true' or 'false'

Tags: jquery, jackson

I am having a problem with passing an array of objects to controller through jackson parser, ajax and jquery.

My controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveTimeBooking")
public @ResponseBody ReturnTO saveTimeBooking(@RequestBody TimesheetTO timesheetTO[]) {
    // ...
}
```

My Java Object TimesheetTO looks like this:

```
public class TimesheetTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int activityMasterId;
    private String name;

    private BigDecimal mondayEffort=new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal tuesdayEffort=new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal wednesdayEffort=new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal thursdayEffort=new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal fridayEffort=new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal saturdayEffort=new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal sundayEffort=new BigDecimal(0);
    public int getActivityMasterId() {
        return activityMasterId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public BigDecimal getMondayEffort() {
        return mondayEffort;
    }
    public BigDecimal getTuesdayEffort() {
        return tuesdayEffort;
    }
    public BigDecimal getWednesdayEffort() {
        return wednesdayEffort;
    }
    public BigDecimal getThursdayEffort() {
        return thursdayEffort;
    }
    public BigDecimal getFridayEffort() {
        return fridayEffort;
    }
    public BigDecimal getSaturdayEffort() {
        return saturdayEffort;
    }
    public BigDecimal getSundayEffort() {
        return sundayEffort;
    }
    public void setActivityMasterId(int activityMasterId) {
        this.activityMasterId = activityMasterId;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setMondayEffort(BigDecimal mondayEffort) {
        this.mondayEffort = mondayEffort;
    }
    public void setTuesdayEffort(BigDecimal tuesdayEffort) {
        this.tuesdayEffort = tuesdayEffort;
    }
    public void setWednesdayEffort(BigDecimal wednesdayEffort) {
        this.wednesdayEffort = wednesdayEffort;
    }
    public void setThursdayEffort(BigDecimal thursdayEffort) {
        this.thursdayEffort = thursdayEffort;
    }
    public void setFridayEffort(BigDecimal fridayEffort) {
        this.fridayEffort = fridayEffort;
    }
    public void setSaturdayEffort(BigDecimal saturdayEffort) {
        this.saturdayEffort = saturdayEffort;
    }
    public void setSundayEffort(BigDecimal sundayEffort) {
        this.sundayEffort = sundayEffort;
    }

    public TimesheetTO(){}

    public TimesheetTO( String activityMasterId, 
                        String name, 
                        String mondayEffort,
                        String tuesdayEffort,
                        String wednesdayEffort,
                        String thursdayEffort,
                        String fridayEffort,
                        String saturdayEffort,
                        String sundayEffort)
    {
        this.activityMasterId=Integer.parseInt(activityMasterId);
        this.name=name;
        this.mondayEffort=BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(mondayEffort));
        this.tuesdayEffort=BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(tuesdayEffort));
        this.wednesdayEffort=BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(wednesdayEffort));
        this.thursdayEffort=BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(thursdayEffort));
        this.fridayEffort=BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(fridayEffort));
        this.saturdayEffort=BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(saturdayEffort));
        this.sundayEffort=BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(sundayEffort));
    }
}
```

And, I am using the following jquery code to pass the array of timesheet objects to controller:

```
var datacounter=0;
/*var totalcount=0;*/
var timesheetTO = new Array();

$("#timeSheetTableId input[id^=activityMasterId]").each(function() {
       $('#activityMasterId_'+datacounter).removeAttr('disabled');
       $('#name_'+datacounter).removeAttr('disabled');

       timesheetTO.push({
           "activityMasterId": $('#activityMasterId_'+datacounter).val(),
           "name": $('#name_'+datacounter).val(),
           "mondayEffort": new Integer($('#mondayEffort_'+datacounter).val()),
           "tuesdayEffort": $('#tuesdayEffort_'+datacounter).val(),
           "wednesdayEffort": $('#wednesdayEffort_'+datacounter).val(),
           "thursdayEffort": $('#thursdayEffort_'+datacounter).val(),
           "fridayEffort": $('#fridayEffort_'+datacounter).val(),
           "saturdayEffort": $('#saturdayEffort_'+datacounter).val(),
           "sundayEffort": $('#sundayEffort_'+datacounter).val()
       });
       datacounter=datacounter+1;
});

var url = contextRoot + "timesheet/saveTimeBooking.htm";
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : url,
    async : false,
    timeout : 5000,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data : {
        timesheetTO : JSON.stringify(timesheetTO)
    },
    success : function(data, textStatus) {
        alert('successful');

    },
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('request failed in saving timesheet:' + errorThrown + " " + textStatus + " "
                + xhr.toString());
    }
});
```

While submitting, I am getting the error as given above : Jacskon parsor exception: Unrecognized token 'tieheT': was expecting 'null', 'true' or 'false'

What am I doing wrong ..is there any way to fix this?

Here is the result of `JSON.stringify`:

```
 [{"activityMasterId":"1","name":"Financial Implications","mondayEffort":"0","tuesdayEffort":"0","wednesdayEffort":"0","thur‌​sdayEffort":"0","fridayEffort":"0","saturdayEffort":"0","sundayEffort":"0"},{"act‌​ivityMasterId":"2","name":"Cost estimation","mondayEffort":"0","tuesdayEffort":"0","wednesdayEffort":"0","thursd‌​ayEffort":"0","fridayEffort":"0","saturdayEffort":"0","sundayEffort":"0"}]
```

Comment: What does the data in JSON.stringify(timesheetTO) look like ?

Comment: It looks like this:                    [{"activityMasterId":"1","name":"Financial Implications","mondayEffort":"0","tuesdayEffort":"0","wednesdayEffort":"0","thursdayEffort":"0","fridayEffort":"0","saturdayEffort":"0","sundayEffort":"0"},{"activityMasterId":"2","name":"Cost estimation","mondayEffort":"0","tuesdayEffort":"0","wednesdayEffort":"0","thursdayEffort":"0","fridayEffort":"0","saturdayEffort":"0","sundayEffort":"0"}]

Comment: I found the solution on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726366/server-unable-to-parse-a-valid-json
(possible duplicate)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are passing a string value which is lacking quotation marks, and the compiler is therefore expecting a boolean/null object.

You should verify what value you are passing at runtime through debugging, by copying it in a text editor to analyze it thoroughly, if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue and now it is working  fine.
The issue might be

```
data : {
        timesheetTO : JSON.stringify(timesheetTO)
    }
```

enclose it in Double quotes

```
data : {
        ' "timesheetTO" : " '+JSON.stringify(timesheetTO)+' " '
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to verify that you are feeding valid JSON: error message indicates this is not the case. It should also give you exact line and row number, which you can use to find the problem with input JSON. From message, I am guessing that either property names are not being quoted, or some String values are not quoted.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax data should take the string of your JSON object. See the solution here:

[Using jQuery to post JSON object to Spring 3 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983556/using-jquery-to-post-json-object-to-spring-3-controller#3987156)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can annotate your class with `@RestController` (if it is not already).
Then you dont need to explicitly annotate your request and response with `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody`

So your method signature will change to

```
@PostMapping("/saveTimeBooking")
public ReturnTO saveTimeBooking(TimesheetTO timesheetTO[]) {
// ...
}
```