# sending a GET request in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
    close: function (event, ui) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});



<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language:</label>
<input id="autocomplete">
```

how do I send the values I get as a GET function ? I read the Ajax GET function but I am not sure how to encode the data I get from the form element

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Serialize**

it will encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

and this how you can make it

```
<form id="myform">
    <label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language:</label>
    <input id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete">
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="send">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("btnSubmit").click(function(){
         $.ajax({'url':'myurlforajaxrequest',
                 'data': $("#myform").serialize(),
                 'type':'get'
               });
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation to [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). The data you pass to it can either be a JS object or a string. The string is basically encoded `key=val` representation of the form elements. Use the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method on the jquery form element to get such a string. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the script you're sending it to expects, but `$.get()` accepts more than one format for the data.  It can be a simple string or an object.

For example, if your script expects a `programminglanguage` variable in the request, your close handler might look like this

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
    close: function (event, ui) {
        var jqxhr = $.get("/my/script.php", "programminglanguage=" + $(this).val());
        // Alternatively:
        //var jqxhr = $(.get("/my/script.php", {"programminglanguage": $(this).val()});
    }
});
```

The [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function has a success handler argument that you might want to use and the properties of the `jqxhr` object that's returned is documented on the `jQuery.ajax()` page [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery **$.ajax** default contentType is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** which mean jQuery will encode the content. However, since you have specify different contentType, the data is not encoded thus you have to do your own encoding. ([Jquery ajax encoding data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263708/jquery-ajax-encoding-data))

Try **encodeURIComponent**. ([URL Encode a string in jQuery for an AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544564/url-encode-a-string-in-jquery-for-an-ajax-request))

> Encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing
>   each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape
>   sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only
>   be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate"
>   characters).

**Example:**

var encoded = encodeURIComponent(str);

**Complete Solution:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css"/>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'yourAjaxRequestHandleFile.php',
            data: 'q=' + encodeURIComponent($('#autocomplete').val()),
            type: 'get',
            success: function (ajxResponse) {
                alert(ajxResponse);
            }
        });
    }
});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language:</label>
<input id="autocomplete">
</body>
</html>
```

**// Here is PHP Code**

```
<?php 
// Get Send Ajax Data
$q = $_GET['q'];
// Show Ajax Data and return to Ajax
echo "You submitted $q ";
?>
```