# Response not getting using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When send email and password and method. that time email is pass like username=userAbig%40bizchatbox.org. So i have faced issue to get response. Please help me how i can fix @ when sending email response using ajax.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $("document").ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://108.161.137.197:8088",
        data: { "method": "GetAuthtoken", "username": "userAbig@bizchatbox.org", "password": "pass" },
       mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
       contentType: false,
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {
       alert(data);
    }
 });
 return false;

 });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to decode?

Comment: First you check the given url call or not using ajax.

Comment: why are you doing multipart I dont see you using any file upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery ajax encoding data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263708/jquery-ajax-encoding-data)

Comment: yes i am tried to decode the email id but it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Getting below response from ajax.

```
{
"Error":"No REST Method found"
}
```

Which means server is not able to find method for your `URL`.

Change `URL` to appropriate one by looking server code.

```
http://108.161.137.197:8088
```

To look like below by verifying server code

```
http://108.161.137.197:8088/myproject/login or
http://108.161.137.197:8088/login
```

Answer (score 0):

URL is perfect. the issue when pass the email id username=userAbig%40bizchatbox.org.  it will pass in UTF format like @ is %40. how i can pass @ in email?